# height: 100% on :before - Is it possible?

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list inside a div and I would like there to be a left border on the list items. I thought a simple `border-left: 5px solid red;` would do the trick, but I want the border on the left of the list numbers. I've tried to get it to work with `li:before`but I can't seem to get the height right.

Is there a way to do this with `:before` or maybe an easier way?

What I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/q5yS6/

Comment: Why not simply attach the border to the `<ol>` element? That should work unless you want a margin between each list item and the border to break between each item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`height` on `:before` works the same as it does with other elements.  A percentage height can only be set if the parent has a set height.  In this case, the parent of the `:before` element is the element it is before.  So you would need to add a height to your `li` in order to have your `:before` element use a percentage height:

http://jsfiddle.net/q5yS6/6/

```
.lists ol li {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 35px;
}

.lists ol li:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Another option to achieve the desired effect would be to set the `li` to `position: relative` and the `:before` to `absolute`.  You would need to remove the `overflow: hidden` though.  You could use `list-style: none` to again hide the numbering:

http://jsfiddle.net/q5yS6/5/

```
.lists ol li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

.lists ol li:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -30px;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

The use of `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` give the effect of 100% height.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `display: flex` for the parent, and `align-items: stretch` to apply the same height to all childs.

Very good doc about CSS flexbox here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

li p {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2 <br> More on that</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
</ol>
```